# ReferenceError: render is not defined onChange input React testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

As a noob I am completely stuck with testing in Jest. Why the terminal is showing referenceErrror, render is not defined. Even when I imported that from @testing-library/react it seems that there is something wrong with my test below. Could some help me pointing to the right direction. I also wrote the SearchBar in a dumb component.

```js
// Searchbar.test.js
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { SearchBar } from './SearchBar';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import getData from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
    getData,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

const setup = () => {
    const utils = render(<Provider store={store}><SearchBar/></Provider>);
    const input = utils.getByLabelText('search-bar');
    return {
        input,
        ...utils
    }
}

test('It should keep a $ in front of the input', () => {
    const { input } = setup()
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'search-bar-test' } })
    expect(input.value).toBe('search-bar-test')
})

// SearchBar.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import { generateSearchButtons } from '../actions/index';

export const SearchBar = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSearchResults()
    })

    const getSearchValue = (e) => {
        const searchResult = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        fetchSearchResults(searchResult);
    }

    const fetchSearchResults = (query) => {
        if(query == null) {
            query = "";
        }
        const searchUrl = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${query}`;

        axios.get(searchUrl)
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch(generateSearchButtons(res.data.meals))
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            SearchBar
            <input aria-label="search-bar" type="text" onChange={(e) => getSearchValue(e)}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your main component file i.e. `SearchBar.js` you have testing code as well. Remove that from below. See the error trace, the `render is not defined` error is in `SearchBar.js` and not in `SearchBar.test.js`